# Statically linking maven and gradle dependencies

Tags: maven, gradle, astyanax

I am using the hector & astyanax projects. These projects used to require maven, and now astyanax requires gradle.

I would like to statically link one of these projects to my java project (which is not built using maven/gradle). I am not interested in updating the version of astyanax every time they make a new release. I am not interested in mavenizing/gradelizing my own project.

So, two problems arise: 1. Getting the astyanax jars. 2. Getting the depenedency Jars.

At first, not having time to thoroughly understand maven (get off my lawn!), I copied all of the jar files in my global .maven directory into my project, and linked to them. Problem is, it's a pretty messy solution.

Is there an easier way to get all jars needed to use a gradle/maven library? (While I don't mind using gradle to build astyanax, I don't want to use it to build my own project).

Getting jars for distribution, seems like a very basic use case, am I missing a simple way here?

Answer (score 0):

astyanax is published to maven central as com.netflix.astyanax:astyanax:1.56.42. Any build tool (Grails, Maven, Gradle, Buildr, SBT) that resolves from Maven can make a dependency on Astyanax and have its dependencies transitively downloaded. That fact that it's built with Gradle doesn't change how it's consumed.

From your question, it's unclear how you want to resolve these libraries. If you don't want to use a tool (Grails, Maven, Gradle, Buildr, SBT), then you'll have to manually navigate every dependencies and its dependencies from Maven Central. It's quite uncommon for a modern java project to manually download dependencies anymore, the practicalness given the complex dependencies graph make it prohibitive.

Comment: I'm ok with compiling astyanax with gradle. I do not want to build it manually, I do however want to build my own project manually. Astyanax requires 13 aditional jars. After I've built astyanax with gradle, is there any way I can get these 13 jar files besides manually combing my local gradle repository? If I want to disribute my project to a user, how can I do so without having access to the binary jars it depends on?